# SwiftUI - How to programatically scroll to top and show a large navigation title?

Tags: ios, swiftui

Recently added to iOS 14 `ScrollViewReader` added a way to programmatically scroll to a view in SwiftUI.

Q: Is there a way to scroll past the topmost element in ScrollView and reveal a large navigation title?

**Expected effect:**
[Large navigation title after scrolling to top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4Wdh.png)

**Outcome:**
[Inline navigation title after scrolling to top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXP4G.png)

Code snippet for reference:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      ScrollViewReader { proxy in
        ScrollView {
          Rectangle()
            .fill(.yellow)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .id("scrollID")
          Rectangle()
            .fill(.blue)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
          Rectangle()
            .fill(.green)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
          Rectangle()
            .fill(.red)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
          Button("Scroll to top") {
            withAnimation {
              proxy.scrollTo("scrollID")
            }
          }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Navigation")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This code scrolls to a top rectangle on the button tap but it doesn't reveal the default large navigation title. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

(I haven't tested it!) Try:

1. declare state var to toggle navigation display mode
2. add .navigationBarTitle("Home", displayMode: showLargeDisplayMode ? .large : .inline)
3. toggle `showLargeDisplayMode` after proxy.scrollTo("scrollID")

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work - the large display mode can't push down to reveal itself. Thank you so much for replying either way.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same thing, but unable to do so. Did you find the solution for this? I see Apple does this for Exercise and Settings app but can't figure out how.